# Making pictures fill the width of an article and how to set the article width to 32,4%

Tags: html, css

"Each article should be floated left, have a width of 32.4%, height of auto and a
border which is dark grey and solid".
"The pictures should take up the full width of the articles and have a height of
200px. This will distort the images slightly, but don’t worry about this".

Comment: while asking questions on StackOverflow, you have to tell us what have you attempted to solve the problem, for example, by attaching your code, instead of just throwing the question on the site

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 1):

```
article {
  border: 1px solid darkgrey;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 32.4%;
}

article img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Full [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZZeBZw) for your assignment.